# How to enable https for access within local network?

Tags: http, https

I have a little server in my local network running some web services, pihole and a nextcloud instance. All services are available via http only and it would be nice if I could switch to https instead, i.e. add encryption.

All the instructions I found in the internet assume that the server is available through the internet and that one wants to encrypt this connection. But I definitely **don't** want to have the server exposed to the internet.

Could someone maybe share a tutorial or so on how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to create a self-signed SSL certificate and install that on your devices to achieve HTTPS
Steps would be:

- create a self-signed certificate, you may follow this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/openssl-self-signed-cert)
- Install the certificate on your devices
- Configure your webserver to use this certificate, (it will vary depending on what web server you use)